# How to click on the highlighted button in selenium ide

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

[image][![***

---

***][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjMyt.png)][1][image][image][image][image]I'm working with selenium ide and I want to click on the button that is highlighted in the calendar that shows today
I have found an order in Selenium that can return the date of the day to me, but I want the date in the Persian solar calendar.

```
 var d = new Date();
 var m = ((d.getMonth()+1)<10)?'0'+(d.getMonth()+1):
 (d.getMonth()+1);
 return d.getFullYear()+"-"+m+"-"+d.getDate();
```

I want to know if it is possible to click on a button highlighted with selenium ide

Comment: What is written inside the button you wish to click on? As we are not Persians...please show examples of the Persian "solar calendar".

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can always click on elements by the text inside them using `Xpath`:

```
String xpathVal = "*//[contains(text()," + "'TEXT')]";
WebElement myElement = driver.findElementByXpath(xpathVal);
myElement.click();
```

Also, you can click on the dropdown (select) and do this:

```
Select select = (Select)driver.findElement(By.id
("ID of select element"));
select.selectByValue("optionText");
// or
select.selectByIndex(2);
```

Comment: This command selects a specific day, but I'm looking to select today

Comment: @mortezazahedi Translate the current day into Farsi day, Farsi month and change my code example with the values you need.